FPS drop while using C++
i am using 120fps camera in 1280*720 res, but i am getting only maximum 30 and if there moments/object moments increases, camera fps decreases up-to 10.  i attached my c++ source file below
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono> // For time measurements

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Open the default camera
    VideoCapture cap("/dev/video2");
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        cout << "Error: Could not open the camera." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    int FPS;
    // Reduce the resolution for lightweight processing
    cap.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280);`
    cap.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720);

    Mat frame, gray, edges;
    auto start_time = high_resolution_clock::now(); // Initial time

    while (true) {
        cap >> frame;
        if (frame.empty()) {
            cout << "Error: Could not capture a frame." << endl;
            break;
        }

        // Calculate elapsed time
        auto now = high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto elapsed = duration_cast<milliseconds>(now - start_time).count();
        FPS = 1000 / elapsed;
        //FPS = cap.get(CAP_PROP_FPS);

        // Convert to grayscale for edge detection
        cvtColor(frame, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        Canny(gray, edges, 40, 100); // Edge detection

        // Probabilistic Line Transform
        vector<Vec4i> lines;
        HoughLinesP(edges, lines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 30, 40, 5);

        // Draw lines on the frame
        for (const auto& l : lines) {
            line(frame, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1, LINE_AA);
        }

        // Display the timer (elapsed time in ms) on the frame
        putText(frame, "Time: " + to_string(elapsed) + " ms", Point(10, 30), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);
        putText(frame, "FPS: " + to_string(FPS) + " fps", Point(10, 60), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);


        // Show the frame with timer
        imshow("Detected Lines with Timer", frame);

        // Update start time after each frame capture
        start_time = now;

        // Exit if 'q' is pressed
        if (waitKey(1) == 'q') {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Release resources
    cap.release();
    destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}

i am expecting to increase fps even in high movement.
note : here is the code which i used to test that camera , looking for more improvement in fps.

Note that operator>> or read is executing 2 operations: grab (supposedly fast), and retrieve (might be slow); Maybe your bottleneck is the frame docoding time, not the camera ability to capture frames. Do you know your camera native codec?

Note that std::chrono::steady_clock is the correct clock for "timing things".  The clock you use is not correct.

You are compiling with optimizations on, right? Have you tried profiling the code what takes most time? Or maybe just timing the individual chunks during the "frame"?

There is almost entirely identical question from 10 years ago. If you think you question is different, please explain why and I would be happy to reopen.

I have a live capture opencv app myself and struggled to get steady frame rates.  I ended up just threading it.  There are dedicated threads for capture, processing and rendering. (Might also help that I used opengl for the rendering and not opencv).

You can read raw images from your camera at 120 fps. However, when you start processing those images, the frame rate inevitably drops. If you try reading images without any processing, you should be able to maintain the 120 fps. Keep in mind that the final frame rate is influenced by both the processing algorithms and your hardware.

No, it's not the processing. do not be misled by good-sounding answers. -- The issue here is the lack of CAP_PROP_FOURCC. it should have been set to MJPG.
